# Is it possible to create custom themes in SP2019?

Tags: modern-experience, 2019

In SP Online we can create custom themes using [theme generator](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric?fabricVer=5#/styles/themegenerator#Overview) and we can use PS commands to push theme and apply. But what about 2019? Here also same way? If yes then how to push the custom theme that was generated to SP 2019 modern sites? I am not able to find any API to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the release notes for SharePoint 2019 custom themes did not make the cut and MS has not made any commitment regarding a feature pack. So the short answer seems to be No.

Source : https://docs.microsoft.com/da-dk/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-2019-development-platform

Comment: could you please provide any support article from MS?

Comment: Answer updated 